# Printing Sub-Class Members in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

Is there a setting in GDB that automatically prints all the members of a (C++) subclass from base-class pointer or do I always have to cast it to the sub-class pointer before dereferencing it.

That is I don't always want to do:

```
p *(SubClass*)baseClassInstance
```

Comment: I would read the documentation if I wondered about something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set print object
show print object

Choose whether to print derived (actual) or declared types of objects.
```

I guess `set print object` is what you need but it works only for polymorphic types.

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_106.html

Comment: `show` will just show the current setting.  He wants `set print object on`.  This really ought to be the default.

Comment: @TomTromey It is not defuault

Comment: Right, but it would be better if it were.  Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: You can add `set print object on` to your `~/.gdbinit` if you want it by default.