# For C++, is it possible to print the superclass members of an object of a derived class

Tags: c++, gdb, member

I've found from googling that it is possible to print the members of a pointer to a subclass object from the pointer to the superclass object simply by casting it, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279395/printing-sub-class-members-in-gdb)

```
(gdb) p *(SubClass*)baseClassInstance
```

Can I do the opposite? For example, in this code snippet, the class GponItf is derived from InterfaceType. When I try to print the members of instance type_m of class GponItf, I get this:

```
(gdb) p *type_m
$161 = (ItfMgnt::GponItf) {
  <ItfMgnt::InterfaceType> = {
     _vptr.InterfaceType = 0xb4f0ea8 <vtable for ItfMgnt::GponItf+8>   > 
  },
  members of ItfMgnt::GponItf:
  static uniqueInstance = 0xee270afc
}
```

Is it possible to display the members in the baseclass InterfaceType? I've also looked at printing the vtbl, but it displays the methods, not the members:

```
(gdb) show print vtbl on
(gdb) print /a (*(void ***)type_m)[0]@10
```

Paul

Comment: GDB is not a C++ interpreter. It supports some C++ features, but that's about it. Having said that, it should show inherited membdrs just fine. Show your code.

Comment: @Paul could you figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The so-called *properties* of a C/C++ class are ordinarily fixed, not dynamic as in other languages – they consist of a contiguous block of memory whose structure is understood at *compile* time by the language. *(Whereas, say in Perl, "an object" is a hash.)*

The *methods* of the class are implemented using the `vtbl`, which point to the executable code that should be invoked with each call.  But there is no such compile-time data structure to describe properties, except possibly for the benefit of a runtime debugger.

Subclasses will *enlarge* the properties area to accommodate storage for the properties that exist only in the subclass, and they might have their own method-table entries as well.

Comment: I don't understand. The compiler knows that GponItf is derived from InterfaceType, and GDB knows that GponItf "contains" InterfaceType. Why can't I display its members?